# Apache Beam Java (SDK versions 2.43.0 - 2.44.0) batch loads to BigQuery fail using Storage Write API

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a batch Apache Beam pipeline that worked successfully until I upgraded from version 2.42 to 2.43 and above. The pipeline uses Storage Write API to write to Biguery and it now fails with the error: `"Error message from worker: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.cloud.biguery.storage.v1.StreamWriter$Builder com.google.cloud.biguery.storage.v1.StreamWriter$Builder.setEnableConnectionPool(bool)'"`.

When I switched to FileLoads method instead of StorageWriteAPI it works again. But wondering what's wrong with StorageWriteAPI now. Tried checking the release notes but couldn't find anything helpful (https://github.com/apache/beam/releases). Can I please get some help here?

Comment: In your pom.xml or gradle build file, the version of `Guava` is v26_0_jre ?

Comment: was this resolved?

Comment: Not sure. It was some time ago. You may try using the latest versions. Hopefully it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a dependency conflict with `Guava` in your `Maven` `pom` or `Gradle` build file. I share with you the `Guava` version I used in my pom file for `Beam` 2.43.0 or 2.44.0 version :

```xml
<guava.version>31.0.1-jre</guava.version>
```

If you use the following dependencies, you have to exclude an old version of `Guava` :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>${google-api-client.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
    <version>${bigquery.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>${pubsub.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I hope it can help.

Comment: Actually the error I see is from org-apache-beam.beam-vendor-guava-26_0-jre. That i think is being used internally by beam and apparently it seems to be the only version available.

Comment: In my example, there are many dependencies where an old Guava version was excluded. Can you share your build file (pom) in your question ?